Rails 7.1, "Is Invalid" on has_many through: Associated Polymorphic Class
When trying to save a new Product::Group, with many Product::Features, I get the error "Features is invalid"
This below gives the error.
class Product::ObjectFeature < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "object_features"
    belongs_to :feature, class_name: "Product::Feature", foreign_key: :feature_id, inverse_of: :object_features
    belongs_to :featurable, polymorphic: true
end

class Product::Feature < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "features"
    has_many :object_features, foreign_key: :feature_id, inverse_of: :feature
end

class Product::Group < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "product_groups"
    has_many :object_features, as: :featurable, inverse_of: :featurable
    has_many :features, through: :object_features, class_name: "Product::Feature", foreign_key: :feature_id
end

However, when I drop the Product and move those files to the root, and clean up the associations it works.
class ObjectFeature < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :feature
    belongs_to :featurable, polymorphic: true
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :object_features
end

class Product::Group < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "product_groups"
    has_many :object_features, as: :featurable
    has_many :features, through: :object_features
end

What am I doing wrong? I have run through every possible combination of inverse_of, class_name, primary_key, foreign_key, source, source_type, etc. between these 3 classes.
I finally gave up and just left them in the root of models, however this is just a temporary solution until I can figure out why its not working.
Anyone have a solution?
-----------------------ERROR----------------------
Processing by Catalog::GroupsController#create as TURBO_STREAM

Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product_group"=>{"arrangement_id"=>"1", "function_pair_id"=>"117", "product_cover_ids"=>[""], "collection_name"=>"", "loading"=>"", "spec_sheet_template"=>"upholstery_group", "feature_ids"=>["", "54", "19", "40"]}, "commit"=>"Create Group", "product_id"=>"974"}

User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Product::Feature Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "features".* FROM "features" WHERE "features"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["id", 54], ["id", 19], ["id", 40]]

app/controllers/default_controller.rb:111:in `set_create_object'

Catalog::Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 974], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:157:in `set_product'

Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]

app/models/ability.rb:9:in `map'

CACHE Product::Feature Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "features".* FROM "features" WHERE "features"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["id", 54], ["id", 19], ["id", 40]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:47:in `create'

TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

Catalog::Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 974], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

Product::Function Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "function_pairs".* FROM "function_pairs" WHERE "function_pairs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 117], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

Product::Arrangement Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "arrangements".* FROM "arrangements" WHERE "arrangements"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 54], ["record_type", "Product::Feature"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 19], ["record_type", "Product::Feature"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 40], ["record_type", "Product::Feature"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

Product::Group Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "product_groups" WHERE "product_groups"."arrangement_id" = $1 AND "product_groups"."function_pair_id" = $2 AND "product_groups"."product_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["arrangement_id", 1], ["function_pair_id", 117], ["product_id", 974], ["LIMIT", 1]]

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

app/controllers/catalog/groups_controller.rb:49:in `create'

["Features is invalid"]



Can you edit the post and provide a stack trace of the error message? That would help get an idea of what is the cause of the problem.

I did get an error, but the message was that it is invalid. It wasn't helpful at all. This was from errors.full_messages

I added the error. As you can see, it offers no new useful information.

Define the classes properly:
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  class ObjectFeature < ::ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "object_features"
    belongs_to :feature
    belongs_to :featurable, polymorphic: true
  end
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  class Feature < ::ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "features"
    has_many :object_features
  end
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  class Group < ::ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "product_groups"
    has_many :object_features, 
       as: :featurable, inverse_of: :featurable
    has_many :features, through: :object_features
  end
end

class Product::ObjectFeature is despite the popular misconception not actually a shorthand syntax. It's misusing an operator that wasn't designed for the purpose to get wonky results. Unfortunately the Rails generators (and guides) are pretty lazily written and just reinforce this bad practice.
The difference is that reopening the class will set the module nesting to [Product, Product::ObjectFeature] so that you can reference other classes inside the same class while it will be just [Product::ObjectFeature] if you use the scope resolution operator.
This means it can only find constants in the outer scope or in the class itself - because thats where you defined the class.
class Foo
  TEST = "I'm defined in Foo"
end

# bad
class Foo::Bar
  puts TEST # uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::TEST (NameError)
end

# good
class Foo
  class Bar
    puts TEST # I'm defined in Foo
  end
end

See the Ruby style guide.

The Product:: addition too 3 of these classes is purely so I can put them into a folder named "Product". They don't actually nest inside the class Product. That is actually Catalog::Product, inside the the catalog folder.
Does that change the solution?

No it doesn't because  class Product::ObjectFeature also nests the constant ObjectFeature into Product. But it does so in a weird, wonky and buggy way.

OK, I copied solution you provided and tried it, but I'm still getting the same "is invalid" issue. What might else be causing this?

See if you can isolate the problem by creating a minimal verifyable example.

I have noticed that this issue only happens when creating new records. When updating, adding or removing those associated records works with no issue.

Although I don't know why, the issue has been solved.
by adding validate: false to the has_many :through, it allowed the items to be saved.
class Product::Group < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "product_groups"
    has_many :object_features, as: :featurable
    has_many :features, through: :object_features, validate: false
end

